# How to get real time updates for a nested collection

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Format of firestore

- collection : coll_base

  - Document : doc1_base
    -subcollection : subcoll_1
    - Document : subcolldoc_1
    - Document : subcolldoc_2
  - Document : doc2_base
    -subcollection : subcoll_2
    - Document : subcolldoc_3
    - Document : subcolldoc_4

I wanted to get all real time updates for all documents till subcolldoc_4 as snapshots
reference : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.